# failed: exceptions must derive from BaseException

Tags: python

I am trying to avoid the BaseException issue here . My requirement is i have a custom exception . when the custom exception is raised, i need to do some commands and need to abort a job.

```
class custom_exp(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.msg)

try:
   #calculating a threshold value 
 # if( above threshold):
     raise custom_exp("hello")

except custom_exp as x:
    # have some code to store the bad records
    raise(message) # this line written to fail the job 
     
except Exception as e:
    # have some code to store the bad records
       raise(str(e))  # this line written to fail the job
```

here is the output

```
  File "C:\Users\gopia\OneDrive - VW Credit\Desktop\untitled1.py", line 11, in <module>
    raise(message)

TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

Comment: You can't `raise` a string, because a string isn't an instance of `BaseException`. You have to `raise` an exception of some kind. What exactly did you intend those `raise` statements to do?

Comment: @rici I am trying to raise a custom exception when a threshold value is reached . How can i modify this code? when a custom exception is captured . i wanted to fail the script too

Comment: If you want to continue raising the same exception from an `except` clause, use `raise` without an argument. If you want to raise a different exception, you'll need to construct one using the appropriate exception object constructor, just like you did a couple of lines earlier.

Comment: Do you want to do anything other than raise the message after catching the exception? In your example you don't need the try/except blacks because you are just trying to re-raising the same exception after catching it. Do you have some code you are running after catching that isn't included here?

Comment: Why don't you just use if-else instead of raising exceptions?

Comment: @paul I have edited the code to show what i am trying to achieve. I wanted  to raise a custom exception .  once the exception is captured , i have some code to store bad records in a file in reject folder . after that i need to fail the job in the exception clause

Comment: Once again: if you want to reraise the same exception, just use `raise` with no argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```py
class CustomExp(Exception):
    pass


try:
    # calculating a threshold value
    # if above threshold:
    raise CustomExp("hello")
except CustomExp as e:
    # store the records
    raise e
except Exception as e:
    # store the records
    raise e
```

Comment: You don't need `e`. `except CustomException: ... raise` does exactly the same thing, slightly more efficiently.

Comment: The reason for the except is because of the requirement to log some information before raising the exception.

Comment: That's fair enough but you can still reraise the exception with just `raise`.